# IMemoryCache Dependency Injection outside controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC Project with an API.

I then have a Class Library in the same solution named **Infrastructure.**

My API calls a repository method inside the Class Library Infrastructure, in the class `UserRepository`

If I use in the API Controller:

```
private static IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
public Api(IMemoryCache cache) //Constructor
{
    _memoryCache = cache;
}
```

I can use the cache into the controller.
But I want ASP.NET to inject the same reference to be used in the `UserRepository` class inside the Infrastructure Library.

This way I can call from the API, a method like

```
UserRepository.GetUser(Id);
```

and in the UserRepository Class:

```
namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class UserRepository
    {
        public static User GetUser(Id)
        {
            **//I want to use the Cache Here**
        }
    }
}
```

How can I tell ASP.NET to inject the `IMemoryCache` into the `UserRepository` class even if is not a controller?

Comment: Please note that static classes (other than for tooling methods and extension methods), singletons (that create instance of itself rather than via DI) and Active Record pattern are **very discouraged** in the C# world and all of them are considered anti-patterns and bad practices as they result in creating code that is hard to maintain and even harder to test

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The concrete solution to avoid all (static singletons, active record pattern and static classes) together:

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserRepository_userRepository;
    public ApiController(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Task<IActionResult> Get() 
    {
       // Just access your repository here and get the user
       var user = _userRepository.GetUser(1);

       return Ok(user);
   }
}

namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class UserRepository
    {
        public readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public UserRepository(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _memoryCache = cache;
        }

        public User GetUser(Id)
        {
            // use _memoryCache here
        }
     }
}

// Startup.cs#ConfigureServices
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but when I try the code I have an error:

 Unable to resolve service for type 'Infrastructure.UserRepository' while attempting to activate...
Should I set up an Interface for it?

Comment: You need to register it in startup of course, either `services.AddScoped<UserRepository>()` or `services.AddScoped<IUserRepository,UserRepository>()`, depending if you split it into an interface or not. You can and you should split it into an interface, this improves testability of your code, though you can also inject concrete classes, but then you lose the ability to easily mock it in unit tests

Comment: This will always give false or null to the cached value. So Cache never works

Answer (score 5):

Dependency Injection and `static`'s don't play nice together. Choose either one or you'll keep ending up with difficulties like this. I suggest you add the `UserRepository` to your dependency injection container, add `IMemoryCache` to the constructor and inject the repository in your controllers.

The key is to implement dependency injection in all the layers of your application, not just in the Web API layer.